# After res.send() event in Restify?

Tags: node.js, restify, bugsnag

I'm trying to add Bugsnag to my Node Restify service. We have a ton of routes already and such so I'm trying not to add Bugsnag calls all over our code base and I'm also trying to do something global so there's never a mistake where a dev forgets to add the error reporting.

Conceptually I want *after* any `res.send()` to get the status code. If the statusCode is >=400 i want to notify Bugsnag by calling `Bugsnag.notify`. I already check for errors everywhere so no errors ever show up to the clients (browsers, phones, etc) but they do get sent, for example, `res.send(401, { message: 'You dont have permission to do that' })` which I'd like to be able to hook into and pass who tried to do that, what route, etc. Problem is I can't get the `after` event to fire at all:

```
server.on('after', function (req, res, route, error) {
  console.log('AFTER')
});
```

I think I misunderstand what `after` is for. It's at the top of my `index.js` before any routes or other middleware (`server.use`) is defined.

My general code structure looks something like:

```
  server.post('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    FooPolicy.create(req, function (err) {
      if (err) return res.send(err.code, err.data);
      FooController.create(req.params, function (response) {
        res.send(response.code, response.data)
        next();
      });
    });
  });
```

FooPolicy == checking permissions
FooController == actually creating the model/data

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `after` event is currently treated like any other handler. That means that if you don't call `next` in every code path, the `after` event will never be emitted.

In the meantime, adding a next call will cause your `after` event handler to fire.

```
if (err) {
  res.send(err.code, err.data);
  next();
  return;
}
```